# Correct query syntax for SQL DELETE via OPENQUERY to linked server

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, sql-delete, linked-server, openquery

I have a Linked Server I am attempting to access through vbscript, to perform a DELETE command. The current syntax for my query string is:

```
DBQUERY = "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(" & strLinkedServer & ", 
'DELETE FROM pacts.acct_posting where posting_number = " & intPostingNumber & "');"
```

This gives a query string of:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(PACTSTEST, 'DELETE FROM pacts.acct_posting 
WHERE posting_number = 170026');
```

However this is returning the error:

> Cannot process the object "DELETE FROM pacts.acct_posting where
>   posting_number = 170026". The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked
>   server "PACTSTEST" indicates that either the object has no columns or
>   the current user does not have permissions on that object.

Permissions for accessing the Linked Server is not at issue.

A quick Googling of the error message reveals a comment from MS that "OpenQuery requires a result set to be returned, but `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and `INSERT` statements that are used with OpenQuery do not return a result set.". They provide some work-arounds, but as I'm not an SQL expert I don't understand the advice they give.

This is at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/270119

Could somebody please advise me what I need to do given the advise at the linked page provided to make my query work?